# How to bridge two lan but keeping their clients using/choosing their own wan?

Tags: vpn, dhcp, local-area-network, bridge, wide-area-network

this is my first question here so please bear with me if I haven't made it super clear

So I have 2 piece of Cisco RV180W router hardware.

The office is moderately big and one single Wifi router is not sufficient to cover them all. So that's why I got two of these routers.

We also have 2 WAN connections so that we don't have a single ISP point of failure. Currently each router is connected to one WAN.

We also have some shared network resources like a Wifi printer, and a NAS.

Current situation is that each router broadcasts their own SSID, so it's like two entirely separate network.
Pro: users could pick their own SSID to switch between ISP.
Con: They have to switch SSID in order to print or use NAS, because the two thing are associated with one of the router only.

So what I am looking for is:

1. Merge the two SSID into one
2. Merge the two network into one (so only 1 DHCP server) so that printers/nas can be shared
3. Users could by some means still pick their own WAN connection (via VPN? some VLAN magic?)

So far I could only achieve 1+2, but not 3.

The way I do 1+2 is simply put one of the router as AP (simply by disabling DHCP on that router and plug a cable between the LAN ports of the two routers; and then set the same SSID and password)

Is there any pro tips on how I could achieve 3 as well?

Although not strictly required, but I would like to keep the amount of additional hardware/server at minimal - best if it can be done just with that two router or maybe the NAS (since it came with also VPN server and DHCP server that I could enable)

I have only little knowledge in VLAN so any newbie-friendly, overly-detailed explanation are more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Users could by some means still pick their own WAN connection

Depends on how you understand "some means". You can assign different gateways via DHCP configuration. You could offer an internal web page which the users can use for selecting the gateway. This page would trigger a script that makes the respective changes to the DHCP configuration file. Ask your favorite search engine for [dhcp multiple gateways].

Comment: Originally I was hoping to look for solutions that doesn't require the admin to do any programming (thus "via VPN? some VLAN magic?"). But this answer definitely is a workable solution somehow. Deserves acceptance.